# (Proof Verification) If $\lim_{k\to\infty}(2k)a_{2k}=0$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}(2k+1)a_{2k+1}=0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose that
>   $\lim_{k\to\infty}(2k)a_{2k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}(2k+1)a_{2k+1}=0$. But
>   suppose that it's not true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$. Then, there
>   are two cases for $na_n$. For first case, $na_n\to L$ for some $L \neq
> > 0$. If so, then we must have all of its subsequences must also
>   converge to $L$. This contradicts the hypothesis. For the second case,
>   where $na_n \to \infty$, for any $M\in\mathbb{R}$ we can find
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $na_n>M$. But this also contradicts the
>   hypothesis because there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n
> > \geq N$ implies $na_n < \epsilon$ since $(2k)a_{2k}$ is one of such
>   $n$. $\blacksquare$

I used proof by contradiction but I want to know if I can derive $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n$ from $\lim_{k\to\infty}(2k)a_{2k}=0$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}(2k+1)a_{2k+1}=0$, from using the definition of the limit or Cauchy.

Comment: There are other possibilities you must consider with this approach.  Why must there be a limit at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, of course you can.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists $N_1, N_2$ such that $n > N_1 \implies |(2n)a_{2n}| < \epsilon$, and $n > N_2 \implies |(2n+1)a_{2n+1}| < \epsilon$.

Let $N = \max{N_1,N_2}$. Let $n > 2N$. Suppose $n$ is even, then $n = 2m$ for some $m > N$, so $m > N_1$, so $|(2m)a_{2m}| < \epsilon$, but since $n=2m$, $|na_n| < \epsilon$.

Suppose $n$ is odd, then $n = 2m+1$ for some $m > N$. Then, $m > N_2$, so $|(2m+1)a_{2m+1}| < \epsilon$, but then since $n = 2m+1$, $|n a_n| < \epsilon$.

Hence, whenever $n > 2N$, $|na_n|<\epsilon$. Hence, we are done i.e. the limit is zero.

---

To give another method, let $b_n = na_n$. We know that $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n+1}$ both converge to $0$.

Now, if $b_{n_k}$ is any subsequence of $b_n$, then $b_{n_k}$ must contain infinitely many odd or even indices $n_k$. If it contains infinitely many odd indices, then it contains a subsequence of $b_{2n+1}$, which is convergent to $0$. Similarly, if it contained infinitely many even terms.

Thus, every subsequence of $b_n$ contains a convergent subsequence which converges to $0$. It follows that $b_n \to 0$, since if not, then for some $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n_k$ with $|b_{n_k}| > \epsilon$ for all $k$, and this sequence cannot have a convergent subsequence, contradiction.

So $b_n \to 0$. This proof also shows that if the natural numbers are broken up into finitely many ordered sequences $s_i$ such that $b_{s_i}$ converges for each $i$, then $b_n$ also converges.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, but it is not complete. What happen is $\lim_{n \to \infty} na_n$ doesn't exists in $\mathbb{R} \cup \left\{{\infty}\right\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Mpre generally,
if $(S_i)_{i=1}^n$
are infinite sets of
positive integers
whose union is
all the positive integers,
and $\lim_{n \in S_i} na_n =0$
for all $i$
then
$\lim na_n =0$.

To prove this,
for any $c>0$,
choose the max $N$
such that
$|na_n|<c$
for $n >N$ and
$n \in S_i$.